# How can i load the binary content of a file in a variable in java?

Tags: java

I have a pdf file "test.pdf" and I want to get the binary content of that pdf and load it in a variable in java? How can I do that?

Should I use ByteArrayOutputStream?
I am thinking something like:

```
Document pdfFIle = new Document();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

byte[] pdfFile = baos.toByteArray();
PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfFile, baos);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at `Files.readAllBytes`

Comment: Generally, the library provides some flow-based APIs. In java we rarely read a file into a byte array at once.

Comment: When you read a file to memory, it's an `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the NIO API, this is simple:

```
byte[] data = java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes( pdfFilePath );
```

This method ensures that the file is closed under all circumstances. Be aware that no checks on the file size are made and this may not be suitable for large files or over a network.